# Php search form shows results without pressing the search button when it should wait until the button is pressed to show them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

As the title suggests I'm trying to show the results of a query and it works properly, but it shows the results automatically beneath the search button, when it should wait for the button to be pressed and then reload the page and show the results. I'm kind of sure that it's a problem with the code but I cannot find where. I know it's a stupid question but all help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Passw0rd') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cvtool") or die(mysql_error());
    include("include/session.php");
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--The viewport tag is used in order to scale the page properly inside any screen size -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>CV Tool</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        <!--Import JQuery from stored file -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--Import JQuery from Google's Content Delivery Network -->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backToTop.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Big wrapper contains the whole site (header,navigation menu,....,footer-->
        <div id="big_wrapper">
            <header id="top_header">
                <a href="main.php"><img src="images/cvlogo.png"> </a>

            </header>
            <br>
            <nav class="clearfix">
                <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="main.php">Home</a></li>
                <?php
                    /**
                     * User has already logged in, so display relavent links, including
                     * a link to the admin center if the user is an administrator.
                     */
                    if($session->logged_in){

                        echo "<li><a href=\"search.php\">Search</a></li>"
                             ."<li><a href=\"myCVs.php\">My CV(s)</a></li>"
                             ."<li><a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">My Account</a></li>"
                             ;

                        echo "<li><a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a></li>";
                    }
                else
                ?>

                </ul>
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
            </nav>
            <section id="main_section">             
                <?php
                    /**
                     * User not logged in, display the login form.
                     * If user has already tried to login, but errors were
                     * found, display the total number of errors.
                     * If errors occurred, they will be displayed.
                     */
                    if($form->num_errors > 0){
                       echo "<font size=\"2\" color=\"#ff0000\">".$form->num_errors." error(s) found</font>";
                    }
                ?>  
            <form action="search.php" method="GET" >
                <h1>Search for an CV</h1>
                <h3>Department</h3>
                <br/>
                    <select id="dropDown">
                        <option value="">Choose a department</option>
                        <option value="Comp">Computer Science</option>
                        <option value="Bus">Business Studies</option>
                        <option value="Psy" >Psychology</option>
                        <option value="Eng">English Studies</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                    <h3>Skills</h3>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="Comp"class="drop-down-show-hide">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Java
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; AI
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Web Development
                    </div>
                    <div id="Bus"class="drop-down-show-hide">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Business 1
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Business 2
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Business 3
                    </div>
                    <div id="Psy"class="drop-down-show-hide">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Psychology 1
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Psychology 2
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; Psychology 3
                    </div>
                    <div id="Eng"class="drop-down-show-hide">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; English Studies 1
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; English Studies 2
                        <input type="checkbox" name="whatever"  />
                        &nbsp; English Studies 3
                    </div>
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready();
                                $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

                                $('#dropDown').change(function () {
                                    $(this).find("option").each(function () {
                                    $('#' + this.value).hide();
                                });
                                $('#' + this.value).show();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </form>
                        <form action="search_result.php">
                            <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />
                            <div id="search"></div>

                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function(){
                                        $("#dropDown").change(function(){
                                            var data = $(this).val();
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type:'POST',
                                                data:'search_value='+data,
                                                url:'search_result.php',
                                                success:function(data){
                                                    $("#search").html(data);
                                                }               
                                            });         
                                        }); 

                                    });


                                </script>
                            </form>                 
                                </section>
                                <footer id="the_footer">
                                    City CV Tool 2014
                                </footer>
                            <a href="#" class="back-to-top"></a>
                            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

it's because of this line

```
 $("#dropDown").change(function(){
```

add a submit button in the form if that's what you want then run the function off that

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

### Edited after rwacarter's correct comments below about accessability

Add an Id to the form tag

```
<form id="searchformSubmit"
```

then do

```
$("#searchformSubmit").on('submit',function(){
```

this should also work if the user presses the enter key to submit rather then the button provided you have only the one form on the page

Comment: Slightly better to add an ID to the form and do `$("#formID").on('submit', function(){`, in case a user is using the keyboard to navigate the form.

Comment: yeah, true. And also if someone presses enter to submit it, I'll update answer

Comment: @Billy, do I replace the $("#dropDown").change(function(){ with $("#searchformSubmit").on('submit',function(){ ? Or I put both of them?

Comment: replace `$("#dropDown").change(function(){ ` with `$("#searchformSubmit").on('submit',function(){ ` and put `id="searchformSubmit"` on your form tag... is that the only form on the page ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the page is reloading is because any `<button>` or or `<input type='submit'>` inside a HTML form **will** reload the page, unless you have `onClick='return false;'` on them. I think you need to add:

```
onClick="startsearch();return false;"
```

on the submit button. You'll also have to send the form data with it. To do this, make a variable with this:

```
var form_data = $('#form').serialize();
```

and send it with:

```
$.post('search_result.php', {form: form_data}, function(data) {$("#search").html(data);})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call (result search) is called when your dropdown change (click, user input, ...), but you should bind the action to your form click

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").click(function(){
            var data = $("#dropDown").val();
               $.ajax({
                     type:'POST',
                     data:'search_value='+data,
                     url:'search_result.php',
                     success:function(data){
                     $("#search").html(data);
                        }               
              });         
        }); 

  });
```

In addition, this is not necessary to specify the action in your form however it will trigger the form action and redirect you to the page `search_result.php`, I suggest you to update it and set `action="#"`